# how to implement a mathematical 3 dimension equations in Java OO

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, chaining

i have this class diagram in order o implement function that applied on the segment 
[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr59z.png)

i need to figure out how can i do this in java using classes an methods

```
if ⁄≤(,)≤  then 
 (−,,)=(,)××(−(,)/ )
```

is segment density and i know how can i implemented this using java objects

any suggestions please

Comment: Great crossover question between SO and Math SE!

Comment: For those of us that aren't mathematicians, can you explain what a segment density is ? Is it a matrix ? Can you show us your code as it exists now ?